# Python garbage collect causes a crontab log error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cron, garbage-collection, urllib2

Here is the goal: a parser that reunites some information from some domains and organize them into one place.

I am a newbie with Python, having chosen to do this job with this language because of learning curve and things.

For the matter, I am doing the parsing with BeautifulSoup lib and that works like a charm. The routine is triggered via crontab in a CentOS 6, Python 2.7.

However, one of my parsing scripts sent me a log with memory error, what was causing the py file to quit without complete its job. Google here and there and found out that some very long html Python parsing would be doing my server ran out of memory. It would be better close, decompose and even garbage collect everything script would not be using there anymore.

Implemented the three things, no more memory errors in the crontab task. However, every time the script runs, I receive an email from crontab with the log of the parsing, what means that  something went wrong there. Checking the databank, all the information was recorded alright, script also completed the entire task, still some error occurred, or crontab would not email me with a log.

In fact, when I run the script directly at the terminal on server, same occurs: the script won’t conclude, unless I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it, it will be frozen in the screen. However, again, looking at the bank, all the tasks where completed without a error.

I tried work only with gc, tried only close() and only release(). Any of these three resources would freeze the screen/generate a log error (however without a error explicitaly in it).

Here is a simple version of what I am doing to better understanding:\

```
class GrabCategories(): 
    def __init__(self):   

        target = 'http://provider-site.com/info.html'
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(target)
            if page.getcode() == 404:
                print 'Page not found', target
                return False
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
            page.close() #not using this anymore, may I close it?
        except:
            print 'Could not open', target
            return

        content = soup.find('div', {'id': 'box-content'})
        soup.decompose() #not using this anymore, may I decompose it?

        c=0
        for link in content.findAll('a'):

            #define some vars

            try:
                catPage = urllib2.urlopen(link['a'])
                if catPage.getcode() == 404:
                    print 'Page not found', catPage
                    return False
                catSoup = BeautifulSoup(catPage.read())
                catPage.close() #not using this anymore, may I close it?
            except:
                print 'Could no open', target
                continue

            #do some things with the page content etc 

            catSoup.decompose() #not using this anymore, may I decompose it?

            if(c%10):
                gc.collect()
            c=c+1
```

Comment: _"some error occurred, or crontab would not email me with a log"_ - no, crontab always sends a mail if a script produces output on stderr or stdout. so what is the content of the mail you receive?

Comment: That's the problem, this output has nothing at all. Crontab write a log with all the queries and transactions done by SQLAlchemy. Thing is that all the others py files that don't use gc or close() or decompose() do not generate any email, and, if I execute via terminal, they complete their tasks without a problem, while this one stuck in the terminal, although all its tasks are completed.  Is there anything wrong with the example code above? Thank you.